# Can't create MongoEventStorageEngine Bean for AxonFramework

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, axon

I am following a basic tutorial for a project with CQRS and EventSourcing.
In the source code of the full tutorial project there is only one configuration class to configure Axon framework for the project, the code is as follows:

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.EventStorageEngine;
import org.axonframework.extensions.mongo.DefaultMongoTemplate;
import org.axonframework.extensions.mongo.eventsourcing.eventstore.MongoEventStorageEngine;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class AxonConfig {
        @Bean
        public EventStorageEngine storageEngine(MongoClient client) {
            return MongoEventStorageEngine
                    .builder()
                    .mongoTemplate(DefaultMongoTemplate
                            .builder()
                            .mongoDatabase(client)
                            .build())
                    .build();
        }

}
```

However, this is not working for me, the IDE warns that it cannot autowire MongoClient, no MongoClient Beans are found, and here:

```
.mongoDatabase(mongoClient)
```

The IDE suggests me to cast com.mongodb.MongoClient to com.mongodb.client.MongoClient

```
.mongoDatabase((com.mongodb.client.MongoClient) mongoClient)
```

But if I try to change that AxonConfig to use com.mongodb.client.MongoClient instead, as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class AxonConfig {

    @Bean
    public EventStorageEngine storageEngine(com.mongodb.client.MongoClient mongoClient) {
        return MongoEventStorageEngine
                .builder()
                .mongoTemplate(DefaultMongoTemplate
                        .builder()
                        .mongoDatabase(mongoClient)
                        .build())
                .build();
    }
}
```

then it can autowire MongoClient and compile successfully, but when I launch the application it fails and I'm getting this output:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'storageEngine' defined in class path resource [com/placidmasvidal/cqrsandeventsourcing/command/AxonConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'storageEngine' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongo' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoClientSettings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration$MongoClientSettingsConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings]: Factory method 'mongoClientSettings' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_BSON_TYPE_CLASS_MAP
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:582) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at com.placidmasvidal.cqrsandeventsourcing.command.CommandApplication.main(CommandApplication.java:10) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongo' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoClientSettings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration$MongoClientSettingsConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings]: Factory method 'mongoClientSettings' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_BSON_TYPE_CLASS_MAP
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoClientSettings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration$MongoClientSettingsConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings]: Factory method 'mongoClientSettings' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_BSON_TYPE_CLASS_MAP
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings]: Factory method 'mongoClientSettings' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_BSON_TYPE_CLASS_MAP
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_BSON_TYPE_CLASS_MAP
    at org.bson.codecs.MapCodecProvider.<init>(MapCodecProvider.java:61) ~[bson-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings.<clinit>(MongoClientSettings.java:60) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration$MongoClientSettingsConfiguration.mongoClientSettings(MongoAutoConfiguration.java:64) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that Mongo as an Event Store is not the most optimal solution out there. This is actually stated on Axon's Reference Guide page (https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/extensions/mongo) because, in essence, it's present for backwards compatibility. This presentation by the founder of Axon Framework explains well why using a dedicated Event Store or RDBMS would be a safer option - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=342tqAORbAM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took some time, but I wanted to have something working on my side before getting back to you and this is what I did.
I've added an [example](https://github.com/AxonFramework/extension-mongo/pull/65) to the [extension-mongo](https://github.com/AxonFramework/extension-mongo) repo where you can check at least a simple working sample.
Still currently a PR but soon to be merged (and I should get back to the answer and update it).

But basically, this is the config I needed to provide:

```kotlin
// omitting the other imports just to have a smaller code block
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient

    /**
     * Configures Mongo as the Storage Engine.
     */
    @Bean
    fun storageEngine(client: MongoClient) = MongoEventStorageEngine.builder()
        .mongoTemplate(
            DefaultMongoTemplate.builder()
                .mongoDatabase(client)
                .build()
        )
        .build()

    /**
     * Configures to use Mongo embedded event store.
     */
    @Bean
    fun eventStore(storageEngine: EventStorageEngine) = EmbeddedEventStore.builder().storageEngine(storageEngine).build()

    /**
     * Configures to use in-memory token store.
     */
    @Bean
    fun tokenStore(client: MongoClient, serializer: Serializer) = MongoTokenStore.builder()
        .mongoTemplate(
            DefaultMongoTemplate.builder()
                .mongoDatabase(client)
                .build()
        )
        .serializer(serializer)
        .build()
```

and on my dependency, I only needed the extension itself:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.axonframework.extensions.mongo</groupId>
    <artifactId>axon-mongo</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Pointing that I am using `spring-boot` `2.4.3`.

Hope it helps you to find the culprit on your side!

Comment: After applying the configuration you provide and checking that I'm using the same dependencies, when I run the project I still get the ```java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_BSON_TYPE_CLASS_MAP``` error.
I leave [here](https://github.com/placidmasvidal/CQRS-and-EventSourcing.git) my code if you want to take a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: Quickly looking there, I think you can remove this dependency `implementation group: 'org.axonframework', name: 'axon-mongo', version: '4.0-M2'`. Also, in which of the modules are you using `Mongo`? I didn't see it anywhere configured as your Event Store.

Answer (score 1):

The `com.mongodb.client.MongoClient` class is the new API and probably is not compatible with the version of Axon Framework that you are using.

To make it work you may need to downgrade your Mongo dependency (`spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb`) and use the legacy API `import com.mongodb.MongoClient`.

Comment: I downgraded data-mongodb to version 2.1.9.RELEASE, which is previous to the tutorial code date and tried then using com.mongodb.MongoClient but it doesn't work, Intellij still warning could'nt autowire and suggesting to use the new mongodb client api. I tried then downgrading also axon dependencies but still not working.
How can I implement a Bean of MongoEventStorageEngine for axon for the new MongoClient API or some other code to do the job of store each event in sepparate mongodb Document?

Comment: It would be very important to know which versions of mongo and axon `extension-mongo` you are using.

Comment: @LucasCampos implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb', version: '2.1.9.RELEASE'
implementation group: 'org.axonframework', name: 'axon-spring-boot-starter', version: '4.2'
implementation group: 'org.axonframework', name: 'axon', version: '4.2', ext: 'pom'
implementation group: 'org.axonframework.extensions.mongo', name: 'axon-mongo', version: '4.2'

Comment: I'm using the 2.1.6.RELEASE version of data-mongodb